# Can't ping router from internal client

Tags: windows, networking

I have the following network layout

Gateway at 192.168.1.1
Subnet is 192.168.0.0/16 (ie netmask 255.255.0.0)
VM-1 at 192.168.2.10 (assigned as static address)
VM-2 at 192.168.3.10 (assigned as static address)
WIN-10 at 192.168.1.50 (assigned by static dhcp entry in the router config)

WIN-10 has perfect connectivity both ipv4 and ipv6.
VM-1 can't ping the gateway using ipv4.
VM-2 also has perfect connectivity.
VM-1 can ping both VM-2 and WIN-10.

I don't understand why its not possible for VM-1 to access the gateway.
As far as I understand how networks work given that both addresses are in the same network they should be accessible.

Comment: Also all machines are running windows 10 pro